# Solve generating function in recurring form

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I have a sequence set as:

$a_0 = 1, a_n = \frac{3}{2}a_{n-1} - \frac{n}{2}$ for $ n \ge 1$

I have started with:
$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$
$$ a_n = \frac{3}{2}a_{n-1} - \frac{n}{2} $$
$$ 2a_nx^n = 3a_{n-1}x^n - nx^n$$
$$ 2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = 3 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_{n-1}x^n) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$

$$  2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = 3x \cdot A(x) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$

I hope these steps are correct, now I'm not sure about this relation:

$$ 2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = 2x \cdot a_0 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^{n-1} = 2x A(x)  $$

And I don't know that to do with the $-\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$.

Could you help me with the above?

// EDIT:
So now I've got:

$$A(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n $$

Which I'm still not sure what to do with that.

Comment: There should be a sum on it. Factor an $x$ and see that it looks like a derivative, so integrate.

Comment: Like integrate the whole sum? @Phicar

Comment: Yes, so you should get a sum that is geometric, use the formula.

Comment: So like: $\frac{ax^{n+1}}{n+1} = \frac{nx^{n+1}}{n+1}$? I'm confused now @Phicar

Comment: no, if you factor an $x$, you have $nx^{n-1}$ which "integrates" to $x^n$.

Comment: We then get: $x\cdot \sum_{n=1} x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct up until
$$
2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = 3x \cdot A(x) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n
$$
You then evaluated the first sum, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$, incorrectly. You cannot "factor out" $a_0$ the way you did. Instead, since we are summing over $n\ge 1$, the only thing missing the $n=0$ term, so the entire sum is just equal to $A(x)-a_0$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
2 \cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n
&=2(a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots)
\\&= 2(\color{blue}{-a_0} + \color{blue}{a_0}+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots)
\\&= 2(-a_0+A(x))\\&= 2(A(x)-1)
\end{align}
$$
For the last summation, we use the following trick, where we notice that there is a factor of $nx^{n-1}$, which is the derivative of $x^n$, allowing us to write this sum in terms of the derivative of another series. You will get used to this trick after seeing it a lot, even though it can be a bit difficult to learn.

Let $D$ denote the differentation operator. For example, $D[\sin x]=\cos x$ and $D[x^n]=nx^{n-1}$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n= 1}^\infty nx^{n}
  &=x\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}
\\&=x\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty D[x^n]
\\&\stackrel1=x\cdot D\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\right]
\\&\stackrel2=x\cdot D\left[\frac{x}{1-x}\right]
\\&\stackrel3=x\cdot \frac1{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:

1. The derivative operator is linear, and distributes over infinite sums.
2. Use the infinite geometric series formula to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$.
3. Evaluate the derivative using the quotient rule.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. So the key here is to apply the differentiation operator multiple times? First to get from $nx^{n-1}$ to $x^n$ -> evaluate that using geometric sum and then to get from $\frac{x}{1-x}$ to $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: I would explain it like this. First, you "un-apply" the differentiation operator. That is, you start with no operator, with $nx^{n-1}$, and then you realize that this is the derivative of something, and write is like $D[x^n]$. Second, then you factor out the $D$, and apply the $D$ operator to the whole function. It is hard to explain in words, but as you continue to study combinatorics, you will see more examples and get the hang of it.

Comment: Thank you. And just a sanity check for myself. The resulting generating function is: 
$A(x) = \frac{2x^2-3x+2}{(1-x)^2 \cdot (3x - 2)}$?

Comment: @popcorn You can use Wolfram Alpha to check your work: [Wolfram alpha computation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+2+*+%28A+-+1%29+%3D+3x+A+-+x%2F%281-x%29%5E2+for+A)

Answer (score 0):

We finish off what you started and fill in some details. We first convert the recurrence into a series:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \frac{3}{2} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n + 1} - \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2} x^n $$

and get:

$$ A(x) - a_0 = \frac{3}{2} \cdot x \cdot A(x) - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n x^n $$

the last term being:

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^n = x \cdot \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^{n - 1} = x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x^n $$
$$ = x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{1 - x} \right) = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2} $$

And so we get:

$$ A(x) - a_0 = \frac{3}{2} x A(x) - \frac{1}{2} \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2} $$

After rearranging and with $a_0 = 1$:

$$ A(x) = \frac{2x^2 - 5x + 2}{(1 - x)^2(2 - 3x)} $$

Applying partial fraction decomposition we get:

$$ A(x) = \frac{2}{1 - x} + \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} - \frac{4}{2 - 3x} $$

Converting the terms above back to series we get:

$$ A(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n x^n = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2 x^n + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(n + 1)x^n - \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 2\left(\frac{3}{2} \right)^n x^n  $$

And so we conclude:

$$ a_n = n - 2 \left( \frac{3}{2} \right)^n + 3 $$

Which we can verify using induction.